# PHP Activerecord: updating array of objects

Tags: php, database, activerecord, phpactiverecord

The following code will return an array of [PHP Activerecord](http://www.phpactiverecord.org) Objects:

```
$book = Book::find('all');
```

Assuming the program is aware of the order of books I can continue and update the attributes of the books and save them to the database as follows:

```
$book[0]->title = 'my first book';
$book[0]->author = 'Danny DeVito';
$book[4]->title = 'Nice Title';
```

in order to save the above I would have to invoke the `->save()` method on each object

```
$book[0]->save();
$book[4]->save();
```

---

1. Is there a better way to do this? built-in [PHP ActiveRecord](http://www.phpactiverecord.org) function
   that saves all members of a given array of objects, or based on an
   association?
2. Assuming the original title of `$book[4]` above was already 'Nice
   Title', would the `->save()` method consider `$book[4]`changed and
   continue with the database save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much research I decided to post my conclusions/answers:

> **There is no such ActiveRecord library function that can update an
>       array of objects with unique values.**

Assuming Activerecord would shoot one update request it would look like this:

```
UPDATE books
   SET title = CASE id
      WHEN 0 THEN 'my first book'
      WHEN 4 THEN 'Nice Title'
   END,
   author = CASE id
      WHEN 0 THEN 'Danny DeVito'
   END
WHERE id IN (0,4)
```

The same question as "*how would I update multiple rows with different values at once*".  This would go against the design of an Activerecord model, as an Object represents a row, and maps rows across tables.  An obvious limitation for having such an easy model to work with.

> **Any assignment to an Object's attributes triggers a 'dirty' flag on
>   that attribute, and any subsequent call to update/save that
>       object will trigger a query even if the assigned attribute value is
>       the same as the database/model's previous value.  Invoking the
>       save() method when no assignments were made does not trigger this
>       query.**

Answer (score 2):

Try using update all insted

```
$update = array();
$update['title'] = 'my first book';
$update['author'] = 'Danny DeVito' ;

$book[0]->update_all(array('set' =>$update));
$book[4]->update_all(array('set' =>array("title"=>"Nice Title"));
```

I think this should be cleaner

Comment: Your example assumes there is only one book, where as the OP has multiple books.

Comment: That's correct @Navarr , I have a form where a user can update several attributes across multiple objects, invoking the save() method 10-15 times on form-submit seems to me overkill and not efficient, database/resource-wise

Comment: thanks for the observation @Navrr ... updated the code. the fact is that still using update_all helps to save duplicate save()

Comment: I don't see a difference, replace to save() methods with two update_all methods.